# how to convert a list of chars and ints to a string

Tags: racket

I have a list of chars and integers, and I'm trying to convert them to a string.

```
> (define l (cons #\a (cons #\b (cons 3 null))))
```

I want to convert this list to the string `"ab3"`.

Using `list->string` doesn't work:

```
> (list->string l)
list->string: contract violation
  expected: (listof char?)
  given: (list #\a #\b 3)
```

When I try that combined with `integer->char`, it gives this numeric value:

```
> (define l (cons #\a (cons #\b (cons (integer->char 3) null))))
> (list->string l)
"ab\u0003"
```

Using `number->string` doesn't work either:

```
> (define l (cons #\a (cons #\b (cons (number->string 3) null))))
> (list->string l)
list->string: contract violation
  expected: (listof char?)
  given: '(#\a #\b "3")
  context...:
   C:\Program Files\Racket\collects\racket\private\misc.rkt:87:7
```

`list->string` requires a list of chars, it does not accept strings.

Another try, first converting the string to a list:

```
> (define l (cons #\a (cons #\b (cons (string->list (number->string 123)) null))))
> (list->string l)
list->string: contract violation
  expected: (listof char?)
  given: '(#\a #\b (#\3))
  context...:
   C:\Program Files\Racket\collects\racket\private\misc.rkt:87:7
```

It does not accept a sub list either. How can I convert this to the string `"ab3"`?

Comment: Your real question seems to be, how do I convert an integer like `3` to a char like `#\3`. `integer->char` isn't the right function for that, because it takes the 3rd ASCII character. What you want is something like `number->string`, right? Are your integers always within [0,9]?

Comment: sorry wasn't aware of that, I want number to string, not number to ascii char code, and the number could be more than 10.

Comment: One thing you can do then, is convert all of the chars to strings, and then use `string-append` instead of `list->string`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to process a list of characters and integers, and concatenate all of them together in a single string. Try this:

```
(define (process lst)
  (apply string-append                   ; append all the strings
         (map (lambda (e)                ; create a list of strings
                (if (char? e)            ; if it's a char
                    (string e)           ; convert it to string
                    (number->string e))) ; same if it's a number
              lst)))
```

For example:

```
(process (list #\a #\b 123 #\c))
=> "ab123c"
```

Comment: The `list->string` already does exactly what `apply string` does, but that isn't the OP's problem. The problem is `integer->char` not doing what was expected.

Comment: In the comments @fluter said that the number could be more than 10, in which case it wouldn't be a character at all. `number->string` is really what's needed, not your `num->char` function. Of course then it's not "how to convert list of char to string," but converting a list of chars and strings to a string.

Comment: @AlexKnauth good grief, I wasn't getting it. _Now_ it should be right, thanks.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it works, just wonder, so this has to make a function, no built-in functions can do?

Comment: @fluter no, there isn't a built-in procedure that can process a list of chars _and integers_. But if you manage to define as input a list of plain chars, you could do this: `(list->string (list #\a #\1 #\2 #\b))`

Comment: Could that `foldr` call be translated into a `map` call?

Comment: @AlexKnauth sure, it's simpler that way. I edited my answer.

Answer (score 0):

A char is a type that has a value. This value is defined in unicode so that `65` is a upper case `A` and a `66` is an upper case `B`. All characters has an integer value and `char->integer` converts from characters to the numeric unicode value and `integer->char` convert from unicode value to a character.

The numeric characters start at `48` (`#x30`) which is the zero to `57` (`#x39`) which is a nine. Thus `(list->string (list #\a #\b (integer->number #x33))) ; ==> "ab3"`

A numeric value can be converted to a string with `number->string`. eg. `(number->string 123) => "123"`. This is displayed in base 10 but if you perhaps want it displayed in hex you can `(number->string 123 16) ;==> "7b"`. Note that `list->string` only takes a list of chars and cannot have other elements like numbers in them.

You may join many strings together with `string-append`:

```
(string-append (list->string '(#\a #\b))
               (number->string #x7b)
               "c") 
; ==> "ab123c"
```

Comment: What's `#x7b`? I know it's hex, but why that instead of `123`?

Comment: @AlexKnauth It's not the first `7b` they see so I'm just using 123 in both bases.

Answer (score 0):

Racket has a handy function called [`~a`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/strings.html#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Fformat..rkt%29._%7E7ea%29%29) that converts its arguments to strings as if by using `display`, and concatenates them all together (Plus a bunch of optional keyword arguments to control formatting, but they're not needed here). Combine it with `apply` to treat the elements of a list as its arguments.

```lisp
> (apply ~a '(#\a #\b 3))
"ab3"
```

(If you're using `#lang racket/base`, you'll have to `(require racket/format)`).